# Стоит ли добавить "не содержит попыток самостоятельного решения" как ещё одну причину закрытия вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, домашки

Часто встречаю вопросы по типу *Нужно сделать бота для Telegram/Discord, чтобы он делал вот это и вон то, помогите.*. Моё мнение – такой вопрос должен быть закрыт, т.к. не содержит никаких попыток самостоятельного решения автором (если мнение неверное, переубедите).

И вот тут возникает вопрос, по какой причине закрывать. На ум сразу приходят две наиболее близкие (которыми я обычно и пользуюсь):

1. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.
2. Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Однако, обратите внимание на формулировку вопроса: *Нужно сделать бота для Telegram/Discord, чтобы он делал вот это и вон то, помогите.*. Как видно, это, скорее всего, не учебное задание, т.к. не похоже на типичную задачу по программированию, да и вообще, не слышал, чтобы на учёбе задавали программировать ботов. Следовательно, эта задача – самостоятельный эксперимент автора, а значит вторая причина отпадает.

Первая причина также не подходит, потому что вопрос явно не об отладке. Автор банально ничего не сделал, следовательно, отлаживать нечего.

Итак, вопрос: может стоит добавить причину закрытия по типу "Вопрос не содержит попыток самостоятельного решения" для подобных случаев?

Comment: Такая причина не нужна. Сколько можно обсуждать одно и то же? Есть же поиск.

Comment: @Qwertiy, наверное, я плохо искал. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, подобными обсуждениями, особенно если там где-то аргументируется Ваше мнение.

Comment: Добавил 4 дубликата.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я помню прошлые обсуждения - такая причина нужна, но есть серьёзные опасения что её будут абузить. Многие участники почему-то путают список стандартных причин закрытия с правилами сайта, и что с этим делать - не понятно.

Даже причина "учебное задание" и та активно "лепится" на вполне нормальные вопросы, удовлетворяющие правилам сайта, при первом же намёке на "домашку" - а под предлагаемую вами формулировку попадает и вовсе любой вопрос не содержащий кода!

Поэтому, если только не начнётся эпидемии вопросов вида *"а сделайте мне X"* - лучше новой причины закрытия не вводить, и обходиться существующими инструментами: минусами и пунктом "Другая причина".

Comment: Тут вопрос с том, что понимать под эпидемией. Я в день штук по 5-7 таких встречаю только по своим меткам.

Comment: _формулировку попадает и вовсе любой вопрос не содержащий кода_ - если в вопросе нет кода, это не означает, что человек не стремится разобраться. Я, например, давно хотел задать вопрос по целесообразности структуры моего проекта, но обошелся своими силами. В вопросе не было бы кода, но было бы стремление разобраться. И действительно, очень много попадается вопросов, в которых автор просит коммьюнити всё сделать за него. Имхо, это неправильно.

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov вот именно, не означает. Но толпа будет думать, что означает, это проверено.

Answer (score 0):

Имхо, всё-таки стоит добавить.

Я считаю, что StackOverflow в первую очередь ресурс для того, чтобы тут помогали, а не решали всю задачу за автора вопроса. Потому что формулировка приведённая Вами в пример (я такие вопросы тоже наблюдал очень часто) выглядит как задание для нас. К тому же, очень много наблюдал вопросов по типу "как сделать запрос погоды от openweather на 5 дней" при том, что это всё очень подробно описано в документации.

Также, лично у меня, при виде того, как автор сам не желает попытаться разобраться в проблеме (даже банально залезть в поисковик/документацию), просто напросто отпадает желание помогать.

Comment: *К тому же, оченнь много наблюдал вопросов по типу как сделать запрос погоды от openweather на 5 дней* – именно после этого вопроса сегодня решил написать данный пост.

Comment: Не нравится вопрос, пройдите мимо. Вы же не один на сайте, возможно есть другие люди, которые в состоянии грамотно ответить.

Comment: @avp, но ведь если на такие вопросы начнут грамотно отвечать (решать задачу за автора вопроса), SO из образовательного ресурса превратится в решебник задачек уровня 9ого класса средней школы. ИМХО это неверный путь.

Comment: @V-Mor, imho вы в корне не правы. SO это не образовательный ресурс и не база знаний. В первую очередь SO это место, где один программист может спросить совета у других. Именно в этом его  сила и ценность (хотя официальная точка зрения и другая). Поэтому чем меньше искусственных ограничений, тем лучше