# Заменить метку "домашки" на "учебные-задания"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, мета, замена-меток

Недавно прошла волна довешивания меток [домашки](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8) на часть вопросов. Всё же, мне кажется, это название не полностью отражает суть. Ведь работа не обязательно может выполняться дома. Лично помню ситуацию, когда прямо с экзамена кто-то пытался задать вопрос и получить ответ. Поэтому мне кажется, что метка [учебные-задания](/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) будет более подходящей. К тому же в таком написании причина закрытия присутствует в движке сайта:

> [image: Закрыть как "учебное задание"]

Отдельно можно ещё обсудить множественное/единственное число, но это уже не так важно.

Comment: Этой метке уже почти год (11 месяцев).

Comment: @Qwertiy совершенно не важно сколько у метки годовых колец пока она не попадалась на глаза.

Comment: Значит кто-то невнимательный ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy модератору виднее

Comment: "_работа не обязательно может выполняться дома_", — забавная аргументация :D А если кто-то выполняет задание на работе?) [tag:рабочие-задания] в студию.

Comment: @nomnoms12 вот поэтому «учебные-задания» и покрывают все такие ситуации.

Comment: а для чего это метка вообще нужна? Так-то можно и "сам не хочу делать сделайте мне срочно" назвать.

Comment: @Эникейщик вообще, конечно, хорошо бы у [автора метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9767/revisions) уточнить. Мой посыл лишь в том, что текущее название какое-то сленговое что ли.

Comment: @Эникейщик метка для обсуждения вопросов, подразумевающих работу за автора. В том числе, их закрытие. Можно подправить описание. И можно добавить синонимов.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен, что название [домашки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8) не очень удачное, но и [учебные-задания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) мне тоже не нравится. Хотелось бы как-то объединить всю группу вопросов не только про домашки, но и вообще про работу за автора, отсутствие попыток решения и подобное, так что предлагаю подумать над другими возможными заменами этой метки.

PS: А сама метка была создана 15 ноября 2019 года - ей двух с половиной недель до года не хватает.

Comment: Опять же [работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10978/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d1%89%d1%91-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80) уже обсуждалась бесчисленное количество раз.

Comment: Никто никак не может прийти к единому мнению, какие вопросы считать работой за автора, а какие нет: атомарные, код не требуется и т.п.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, тут обсуждается сама метаметка, а не работа за автора.

Comment: Что ж... Тогда могу добавить вариант просто "Учеба". Краткость - сестра таланта. Ну просто как предложение:) Хотя вариант "Учебные задания" мне кажется не плох

Comment: Метке уже один год

Comment: @Danis, надо её поздравить)))

Comment: "сделай за меня"...по-моему отличное название для метки)

Answer (score -1):

Заметил здесь [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10982/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#comment47341_10983) такой:

> "сделай за меня"...по-моему отличное название для метки)

И подумал, а что если действительно выбрать для (основной) метки такое название, которое бы (немного, ну т.е. самую малость) пристыжало вопрошающего. Варианты (не без юмора):

- [сделай-за-меня](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f)
- [я-лентяй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%b9)
- [нет-времени-сделать-самому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83)
- [помогите-люди-добрые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5)

Т.е. вопрос является разрешённым на сайте, но быть автором такого вопроса считается не очень круто. Или это всё же идёт в разрез с ценностями Stack Overflow?

Comment: Я думаю это абсолютно идет в разрез с Be Nice.

Comment: Конституция, уголовный и административный кодексы и всякие международные конвенции пристыжают многие действия. Что-то ни помогает...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну, если бы убийство/грабёж и прочее насилие не наказывалось, наверное, их было бы больше.

Comment: Наказывают правоохранительные органы. На сайте это бравые модераторы. / Я не против толики юмора, но это нисколечко не поможет, к сожалению.