# Что следует делать с вопросами без кода при проверке? Комментировать или оставлять тревогу?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, очередь-проверок

Мне в очереди првоерок "Сообщения низкого качества" попал следующий вопрос: [Swi-Prolog: Два списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254616/swi-prolog-%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0) (изначальная версия - без правок).

Он, очевидно, плохой, так как не содержит кода, но является вопросом "Как мне сделать, а лучше сделайте за меня". Участник, задавший его, – новичок.

Что мне следует делать с таким вопросом? Следует, наверное, оставить комментарий типа "Добро пожаловать... Советую ознакомиться с... Вы можете править вопрос, нажав кнопку править... В текущем виде вопрос не соответствует теме сайта..."

А потом? Я могу:

- **Выглядит нормально** - точно не подходит, ибо вопрос не выглядит нормально ни с какой стороны.
- **Править** - я не могу править вопрос, потому что, во-первых, не могу добавить код самого ТС, во-вторых, не знаю `[prolog]`
- **Рекомендовать удаление** - напрашивающийся вариант. Однако правильным ли он будет, если, во-первых, участник - все же новичок и он может не понять, почему его вопрос закрыт, и что ему делать, а во-вторых, я оставлю комментарий и автор, возможно, сразу исправит вопрос, сделав его вполне хорошим, а удаление я уже рекомендовал.

**Так что же делать?**

P.S. Вопрос не об этом конкретно посте, а в целом: что по пунктам делать в плохими вопросами, которые могут быть улучшены автором, но не мной.

Comment: Опять? Да ничего не делать, сейчас дубликаты найду.

Comment: И приведённый вопрос плохим не является.

Comment: @Qwertiy Как не является? А как же "Приложить свой код, показать, что имеется, что уже написал сам, сайт - не фрилансовая биржа" и т.д., и т.п? Куда же это все?

Comment: Держи ответ. Закрывать как дубликат или оставить?

Comment: @Grundy, маловато дубликатов.

Comment: Если вы не знаете prolog (как вы пишете), то самым разумным будет никак не реагировать на этот вопрос

Answer (score 3):

> Мне в очереди првоерок "Сообщения низкого качества" попал следующий вопрос: [Скрестить два списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254616/swi-prolog-%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0) (изначальная версия - без правок).

Именно <kbd>Выглядит нормально</kbd> потому что вопрос действительно выглядит нормально. Более того, он хороший потому что автор не просит написать за него программу целиком, не спрашивает о вводе и выводе списков, а ставит конкретную задачу: скрестить два списка. Да, есть немного корявостей в формулировках, которые можно было бы исправить, но в целом вопрос хороший.

> Он, очевидно, плохой, так как не содержит кода

Это вообще не критерий качества вопроса. Уже обсуждалось:

- [Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3851/178988)
- [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/178988)
- [Переводы тривиальных вопросов с ангийского so](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4224/178988)
- [Что делать с вопросами по типу "нужно решить задачу, но сам я ничего не сделал"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9631/178988)

Вообще, в причинах закрытия ничего не говорится про отсутствие кода. Даже в ужасной причине про домашки формально наличие кода не упоминается. И уже сколько было попыток её исправить, но некоторые постоянно сопротивляются.

- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 3: “текст задачи” — это не отсутствие кода!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5953/178988)
- [Нужна ли нам причина закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9704/178988)
- [Что будем делать с причиной закрытия "учебные задания"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10070/178988)
- [Причина закрытия «учебные задания»: дубль два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10141/178988)
- [Стоит ли добавить "не содержит попыток самостоятельного решения" как ещё одну причину закрытия вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10978/178988)

Что с ней надо сделать, я предлагал, например, тут:

- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9710/178988 (+14 -1)
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988 (+27 -3)

> Вопрос не об этом конкретно посте, а в целом: что по пунктам делать в плохими вопросами, которые могут быть улучшены автором, но не мной.

Оставлять автору комментарий с тем, что он может улучшить.
В принципе, можно голосовать за закрытие, но точно не за удаление.

Comment: Согласен, вопрос норм. А то так можно все назакрывать.

Comment: И для базы знаний эти попытки решения не нужны, т.к. тому, кто ищет правильное решение, неправильные решения не интересны.

Comment: @КириллМалышев Хаха нет. У меня бывает ищешь на enSO и находишь вопрос с неправильным кодом. Но ответ тебе не подходит, зато берешь и исправляешь код из вопроса. И думаешь: вопрос помог больше чем ответ lol